# How to (properly) map Active Directory attributes to outgoing claims?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, adfs

So I'm trying to figure out how to map employee numbers from active directory as claims in my claims-aware app. We need some kind of key-value in our app so that accounts don't get orphaned when people change their names (marriage etc.).

What's the proper way to map these attributes as claims? Below I've done it in what *seems* to be the obvious way to do it, but on login, we're getting 'an error occurred' and an entirely useless error message, which I will attach at the bottom.

[image]
[image]

[image: Active Directory Attributes]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem, just use the settings in the question (they have been edited to reflect some changes I made). These will work to add an employee number to an outgoing claim in ADFS 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

1.There's no built-in "EmployeeNo" such claim unless you created the custom claim yourself. You can find all the supported claims on the Claim Descriptions node.

2.When you use the "Send LDAP Attributes as Claims" you should make sure the attribute (Employee-Number in your case) has been populated in AD because when the Claim Rule engine runs it will lookup the AD database for this attribute value.

3.UPN, Email Address, Common name, at least one of these three identity claim types must be present for a token to be issued. Commonly we use UPN as the identity of the user. So you can also add UPN in the Issuance Transform Rules.

Comment: Let me clarify, the other claims are present. I was trying to do it in a separate rule. Hang on for screenshot.

Comment: Ah okay, so I've found the list of supported claims. employeeNumber isn't in the list, what's the next step?

Comment: Oh nevermind, the settings above worked. When I remoted into the ADFS server, it looks like I hadn't saved my last changes, which actually fixed the issue. Doh!